# If $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n}x^n$ for $x \in ]-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}[$ then what is $f'(x)$?

Tags: summation, power-series

> If $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n}x^n \: \: \text{for}\: \: x \in ]-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}[$$ then what is $f'(x)$?

**Attempt**

It turns out that $\rho = \frac{1}{2}$ is the radius of convergence for this series. Since $f(x)$ has the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nx^n$, where $c_n = \frac{2^n}{n}$, we know that
$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nnx^{n-1} $$
Plugging in $c_n$ I get

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2 \cdot 2^{n-1} \cdot x^{n-1} = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2x)^{n-1} $$

I feel I'm close, but I can't figure out what the next step should be.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k=\frac{1}{1-q}$ for suitable $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula).

$$f'(x)=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2x)^n = \frac{2}{1-2x}$$